# Subquery in Update statement not working in Snowflake

Tags: sql, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am running below query in Snowflake:

```
UPDATE PROVIDER_XO_SCORE_TABLE AS PXS 
SET PXS.PROVIDER_ID = (SELECT P.PROVIDER_ID 
                       FROM PROVIDER_TABLE P 
                       WHERE PXS.XPI = P.XPI);
```

This query working fine in MySql but giving below error message in Snowflake.

**SQL compilation error:**

> Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the join-like syntax with `UPDATE...FROM`:

```
UPDATE PROVIDER_XO_SCORE_TABLE PXS 
SET PROVIDER_ID = P.PROVIDER_ID
FROM PROVIDER_TABLE P 
WHERE PXS.XPI = P.XPI;
```